# が in: 彼はその子供がついてこられるようにゆっくり歩いた

Tags: particle-が

reading this sentence confused me (it's not that hard to do actually XD).

彼はその子供がついてこられるようにゆっくり歩いた。

Can i ask if the が in this sentence is actually acting like けど, a ぎゃくせつ if thats the word?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The が is a subject marker. その子供 is the subject of ついてこられる.

You can parse it this way:

> 彼は（その子供がついてこられるように）ゆっくり歩いた。
>   "He walked slowly, (so that the child could follow him.)"

<sub>You could rephrase it as 「その子供がついてこられるように、彼はゆっくり歩いた。」</sub>

彼は is the subject of ゆっくり歩いた. "He walked slowly." This is the main clause.
その子供がついてこられるように "so that the child could follow him" is a subordinate clause.

Comment: Thanks chocolate:
 what change would make is so "he walked slowly (so he could follow the child)"

Comment: @shaunoanime "He walked slowly (so he could follow the child)." は、「彼は、その子供**に**ついていけるようにゆっくり歩いた。」になると思います。

Comment: thankyou. From your second example i realised i viewed ついてこられる as receptive.